# JPA @ManyToMany with JoinTable Duplicate entry issue

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa, jpa-2.0

I have a bidirectional `ManyToMany` relation between **Address** and **Group**.
I got the following persisted in my DB:

- 3 addreses: addr1, addr2, addr3
- 1 group named group1

When group1 holds addr1, meaning the Join-Table `groups_addresses` holds a single entry with the id of addr1 and the id of group1.

I'm trying to add addr2 to group1 as well:

```
AddressGroup group1DataObj = groupsRepository.findById(group1Id);
Address addr2DataObj = addressesRepository.findById(addr2Id);
addr2DataObj.addGroup(group1DataObj);
groupsRepository.save(group1DataObj);
```

But for some reason I'm getting `ConstraintViolationException`:

```
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '2c355601-02c9-459a-83f4-27720bc5d61f-01b08cbf-bfeb-4c71-969e-135' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

At the beginning I was missing the `CascadeType.PERSIST`, after adding it to both sides still getting the same exception.
I'm using hibernate as a JPA implementation and below are my entities, where could I go wrong?

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "addresses")
public class Address implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "com.sample.app.UseExistingOrGenerateGenerator")
    private String id;

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
            cascade =
                    {
                            CascadeType.PERSIST,
                            CascadeType.DETACH,
                            CascadeType.REFRESH
                    },
            targetEntity = AddressGroup.class)
    @JoinTable(name = "groups_addresses",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "address_id",
                    nullable = false,
                    updatable = false),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "group_id",
                    nullable = false,
                    updatable = false),
            foreignKey = @ForeignKey(ConstraintMode.CONSTRAINT),
            inverseForeignKey = @ForeignKey(ConstraintMode.CONSTRAINT))
    private Set<AddressGroup> groups;


    public void addGroup(AddressGroup group) {
        //avoid circular calls
        if (!groups.contains(group)) {
            groups.add(group);
            //add method to Product : sets 'other side' of association
            group.addAddress(this);
        }
    }

    public void removeGroup(AddressGroup group) {
        //avoid circular calls
        if (groups.contains(group)) {
            groups.remove(group);

            //handle other side of association
            group.removeAddress(this);
        }
    }

    public Address() {
        groups = Sets.newHashSet();
    }


        // Getters & Setters ....
}
```

=================================================================

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "groups")
public class AddressGroup implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator")
    private String id;

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,
            cascade =
                    {
                            CascadeType.PERSIST,
                            CascadeType.DETACH,
                            CascadeType.REFRESH
                    },
            targetEntity = Address.class)
    @JoinTable(name = "groups_addresses",
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "address_id",
                    nullable = false,
                    updatable = false),
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "group_id",
                    nullable = false,
                    updatable = false),
            foreignKey = @ForeignKey(ConstraintMode.CONSTRAINT),
            inverseForeignKey = @ForeignKey(ConstraintMode.CONSTRAINT))
    private Set<Address> addresses;

    public void addAddress(Address address) {
        //avoid circular calls
        if (!addresses.contains(address)) {
            addresses.add(address);
            //add method to Product : sets 'other side' of association
            address.addGroup(this);
        }
    }

    public void removeAddress(Address address) {
        //avoid circular calls
        if (addresses.contains(address)) {
            addresses.remove(address);

            //handle other side of association
            address.removeGroup(this);
        }
    }

    public AddressGroup() {
        addresses = Sets.newHashSet();
    }


    // Getters & Setters ....

}
```

Comment: Try using 
addressesRepository.save(addr2DataObj); instead of saving Group

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've changed the annotation in class `Address` following [this post](https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/hibernate-tips-map-bidirectional-many-many-association/) and it got solved. I used the `mappedBy` attribute:

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "addresses", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private Set<AddressAliasGroup> groups;
```